# Are there any resources for learning CG related math (especially the math used by Blender)?

Tags: mathematics

I want to get involved in developing Blender, maybe writing add-ons and stuff for the community. As far as I can tell, there's a lot of math involved with this (generally stuff like matrix/vector algebra, dot/cross products, quaternions, and complex numbers, and I'm sure a lot of other stuff); are there any resources for learning this stuff (in particular, that focus specifically on CG applications): books that are generally in high regards in the blender community or tutorials?

**Addendum:** I feel I should mention, I don't find my post to be a duplicate of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender). First off, my question is about resources specific to *learning CG related math and how it is implemented, specifically in a CG context* (i.e. other applications of the math are not important.Because of this and a heavy emphasis on various algorithms, I also felt it would be considered off topic on the math SE), conversely, the other post appears to be focused on resources for *using blender* (add-ons, stock images/textures, other software that can be used along side it, tutorials on using it, etc.). I'm not looking for books on how to drive a car or looking for a different engine to add on; I'm looking for books on how engines work. What are the formulae for ray tracing, how do quaternions work, etc.

Secondly, math is a really fundamental part of CG works; I would think that since the other post didn't so much as even mention math (the closest thing I could find was some documentation about the Python API but even that is still pretty far off the mark), it wasn't because it was some tiny, obscure topic that was overlooked. So, it stands to reason that the resources I'm looking for aren't a good fit for it.

Comment: @RayMairlot I've written an addendum to specify why I don't feel this is a duplicate.

Comment: The reason that question exists is because normally these sort of questions are considered off topic, however I agree that the lack of maths resources is a pretty big oversight, so I have started a section there: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/135314#135314.